# Rendering JSON array in React component

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am trying to display an array of strings coming from an API. But I am not able to iterate through that array. If I pass the whole array inside HTML tag then it is rendering as a string.

For example: `<div>{data.list.ingredients}</div>` is working and displaying as a string. If I try to console this `data.list.ingredients[0]` it is throwing an error:

```
Cannot find 0 of undefined
```

My array:

```
{
  "_id": "5b5446df2c89ab3d0e8d5526",
  "title": "Chicken with Mustard Cream Sauce",
  "vegetarian": false,
  "ingredients": [
    "4 whole Boneless Skinless Chicken Breasts",
    "2 Tablespoons Olive Oil",
    "2 Tablespoons Butter",
    "3 whole Garlic Cloves Minced",
    "1 cup Brandy",
    "1 Tablespoon (heaping) Dijon Mustard",
    "1 Tablespoon (heaping) Grainy Mustard",
    "1/4 cup (to 1/2) Heavy Cream",
    "1/4 cup (to 1/2) Chicken Broth",
    "Salt And Pepper"
  ],
  "image_url": "http://static.food2fork.com/chickenmustarde587.jpg",
  "steps": [
    "Amount of cream and broth has slightly decreased add more as needed",
    "Cut the chicken breasts in half lengthwise so that you have eight smaller thinner chicken cutlets Salt and pepper both sides",
    "Heat oil and butter in a large skillet over mediumhigh heat Cook cutlets on both sides until nice and golden brown and cooked through Remove chicken from the skillet and keep on a plate",
    "Reduce the heat to medium Add the garlic to the pan and saute it for a minute stirring to make sure it wont burn Next pour in the brandy or wine if using being careful if cooking over an open flame Then just let the booze bubble up and cook until its reduced by half",
    "Throw in the mustards and stir to combine then pour in the cream Stir in chicken broth adding more if the sauce seems too thick Taste sauce and adjust whatever you think it needs Add chicken breasts back to the pan nestling them into the sauce Allow sauce to cook for another few minutes shaking the pan if needed to move things around",
    "Serve chicken with a green salad spooning the sauce over the top"
  ],
  "serving": 5,
  "cooking_time": 20
}
```

Comment: Your question is really not clear. Just use map function and render it : const t=array.map(s=><div key="..somekey">{s}<div/>) , and then render 't'

Comment: Without the guilty code, it will be hard to help you. Can you provide the code that retrieve data, and the lines involved in the render method? Thanks.

Comment: My code is not considering ingredients as an array. If i try to access first value of ingredients array, it is throwing an error. Is it below I am getting this data object from an API?

Comment: Can you show your api calling code?

Comment: Here it is: `getData = query => {
    const { sendInitialRecipeList, setInitialSelectedRecipe } = this.props;
    fetch(`http://localhost:8000/recipes/?dish=${query}`)
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(response => {
        sendInitialRecipeList(response);
        setInitialSelectedRecipe(response[0]);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };`

Answer (score 0):

```
function renderData(){
  let array = ['a','b','c','d' ];
  return array.map((item, index) => <div key={index}>{ item }</div>);
}
```

Comment: Using array `index` as key is a bad practice, be careful with that.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using axios (API component) so in your case you can get the result as follows:

```
axios.get('/youringredients.json')
  .then(res => {
  const ingredient = res.data.list.ingredients[0];
  console.log(ingredient);
});
```

you can use ingredient in your state also.

Comment: I am not using axios. `getData = query => {
    const { sendInitialRecipeList, setInitialSelectedRecipe } = this.props;
    fetch(`http://localhost:8000/recipes/?dish=${query}`)
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(response => {
        sendInitialRecipeList(response);
        setInitialSelectedRecipe(response[0]);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };`

Comment: You can use JSON.parse() to convert your json string into javascript object and then use that object for your needs.